# How to use AWS iOS SDK to delete an object?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to delete a public image (`cannedACL` property of the `S3PutObjectRequest` to upload the image was `[S3CannedACL publicRead]`) uploaded to an S3 bucket.

There is an `S3DeleteObjectRequest` class in the AWS SDK [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/), but there don't seem to be any properties or initialization methods for [this class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/S3DeleteObjectRequest.html).

Based on sample code in other languages, it looks like there should be `key` or `bucket` property or an initialization method setting those properties, as there are in the iOS SDK's [`S3PutObjectRequest`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/S3PutObjectRequest.html) class, used to upload files to a bucket.

What's going on here? Is the SDK simply incomplete? Is there a way to delete an object with the iOS AWS SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just going off the documentation you linked to, but does this not work?

```
[s3Client deleteObjectWithKey:@"objectKey" withBucket:@"my-bucket"];
```

Answer (score 8):

For the iOS SDK for S3 V2, this code came in handy

```js
AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
                AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *deleteRequest = [AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest new];
                deleteRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;
                deleteRequest.key = climb.imageKey;
                [[[s3 deleteObject:deleteRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                    if(task.error != nil){
                        if(task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused){
                            NSLog(@"%s Error: [%@]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.error);
                        }
                    }else{
                        // Completed logic here
                    }
                    return nil;
                }] waitUntilFinished];
```

This is based heavily upon the unit tests that have been written for the library here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSS3Tests/AWSS3Tests.m

Answer (score 1):

Art Gillespie's answer worked just fine for me as well.

However, I also discovered that you can achieve the same by setting the `key` and `bucket` attributes on the S3 delete object request:

```
S3DeleteObjectRequest *dor = [[S3DeleteObjectRequest alloc] init];
dor.key = AWS_OBJ_PATH;
dor.bucket = AWS_BUCKET;

[s3Client deleteObject:dor];
```